# Net::HTTP.get SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)

Tags: ruby

I have an issue where the minimal reproduction is:

```rb
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("https://localhost:3000"))
```

```
/Users/dorianmariefr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:46:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate) (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I have the certificate in my macOS certificate trust store so that's weird, and going to localhost:3000 on the web browser works fine.

So how can I add a self-signed certificate to ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with:

```
SSL_CERT_FILE=~/.localhost/localhost.crt sidekiq
```

Thanks to this great article https://mislav.net/2013/07/ruby-openssl/